# jQuery Carousel with image in feature

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

I need to do this slider and I have found a few codes and tried, but none were exactly [LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkjEk.jpg)

```
<div class="bloco03 center" id="bloco03">
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image06.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image07.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image06.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image07.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image06.jpg"></div>
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image07.png"></div>
    <div><img src="images/clientes/image06.jpg"></div>
</div>

.bloco03 img {
    width: 100%;
}

$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 5,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I used Slick http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ , I had a few issues with the design of the arrows and the image is not featured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I agree that using Slick in "center mode" is the correct approach. 
It looks like the next thing you'll want to customize is the "center" image.
Create a new CSS rule that targets ".slick-center" and use transform:scale to increase the size of the centered image. You may also need to create a CSS rule for ".slick-list" and declare overflow:visible so that the newly scaled image is not cropped by the outer container.
The next thing you'll want to customize is the location of the arrows. You'll want to use absolute positioning to place them above the carousel. The class names of the arrows are usually ".slick-prev and .slick-next". I'd suggest adding a parent container outside of the carousel and set it to relative positioning. Then play with the left, right, top, bottom values to place it where you want it.
Good luck!